# Subset of cartesian products

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that $A \subset C$ and $B \subset D \iff (A \times B) \subset (C \times D$).

Comment: Try mutual subset inclusion to show equality (via an element-chasing proof).

Comment: To start, you'll suppose the lefthand side, and show the right, then you'll suppose the righthand side and show the left (or in the opposite order). I'll start you on the forward implication ($\implies$):


If $A\subset{C}$, then every element of $A$ is in $C$. Similarly, if $B\subset{D}$, then every element of $B$ is in $D$. The cartesian product $A\times B$ in set-builder notation is $A\times B=\{(a,b):a\in{A}\text{ and }b\in{B}\}$. You'll need to show that every element of that cartesian product is in the cartesian product $C\times{D}$.

Comment: is it always true

Comment: @setb You don't know if the statement you are trying to prove is, in fact, true? Then try several examples at first. If none seem to contradict the claim, then try to do what I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Be $(a, b) \in A \times B$. Then, $a \in C$ and $b \in D$, because $A \subset C$ and $B \subset D$. So, $(a,b) \in C \times D$. Therefore, we can concluded that $A \times B \subset C \times D$.

For the reverse, I think (not sure) that is not worth.

We need to give a counter example.

Comment: If the sets are all not empty it is true. If $A$ or $B$ (but not both) there exist cases that does not work.

Comment: Perfect @YotasTrejos. Very cool. So really the reverse not is given that $A$ and $B$ can be empty sets.